# How to dispatch gesture from AccessibilityService onGesture

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, android-gesture, android-touch-event

I'm trying to build an app that can detect different gestures and then perform some action. I'm able to detect gestures using AccessibilityService onGesture method.

But I want to dispatch the gesture so that user actions are not blocked. How can I dispatchGesture from AccessibilityService onGesture method

```
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyAccessibilityService";

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent: " + accessibilityEvent.getEventType());
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onInterrupt: something went wrong");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onGesture(@NonNull AccessibilityGestureEvent gestureEvent) {
        super.onGesture(gestureEvent);
        int gestureId = gestureEvent.getGestureId();

        GestureDescription.Builder gestureBuilder = new GestureDescription.Builder();

        Log.d(TAG, "onGesture: Gesture Detected " + gestureId);
        switch (gestureId){
            case 17:
                Log.d(TAG, "onGesture: Double Tap Happened");
        }

        GestureDescription gestureDescription = new GestureDescription.Builder().build();
        dispatchGesture(gestureDescription, new GestureResultCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GestureDescription gestureDescription) {
                super.onCompleted(gestureDescription);                
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(GestureDescription gestureDescription) {
                super.onCancelled(gestureDescription);                
            }
        }, null);

        return true;
    }

}
```